# Expand row immediately after populating ui grid with data?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, expand, expandable, angular-grid

I want to expand the row in the ui grid immediately after populating it with data.

This is the function for populating the data.

```
    $http({
        url: '/Parameters/GetQuarterJson',
        data: { AccountID: $scope.selectedProject, Year: $scope.selectedYear },
        method: 'POST'
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.quarterGrid.data = response.data;
    });
```

And this is the function which is called based on some condition right after populating data  to expand the row.

```
    $scope.paramerterGridApi.expandable.collapseAllRows();
    var index, rows = $scope.quarterGrid.data;
    //$scope.quarterGrid.data contains the new data

    for (index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
        if (rows[index].Quarter === $scope.selectedQuarter) {
            $scope.paramerterGridApi.expandable.expandRow(rows[index]);
         //but $scope.paramerterGridApi.grid.rows doen't contains it

        }
    }
```

That's why the row doesn't expand. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you please create demo in Plunker with your problem?

Comment: I think it is not possible since the ajax calls are for the ASP MVC action methods which fetches the data from database and process it before returning as Json. If I can make one please tell me how.